# laravel one to many record insert and update solution

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables one is "ITEM" and second one is "Composite Item" in mysql database. I am trying to insert multiple items id in composite item table for one single record in laravel.

One of logic I have tried to save multiple items id as comma separated value for example "1,2,3,4" and also update that one field as same concept. but I am having issue when i delete any one item from item table. if i delete any of the item from item table how can i delete that same item from string item ids in composite item table. for example from item table i have deleted item id 3.

also i have think if i create new table for one to many relation then how can i update record when i update record.

Comment: use foreach loop for saving the composite items.

Comment: Can an item be a part of more than one composite item?

Comment: @KuldeepMishra  i can use foreach loop for add composite item. is there any way how can i update composite items ?

Comment: @SakiburRahman  base table is item table. composite item is dependent on item table. item table is not dependent on composite item.

Comment: Yeah, can two separate composite items consist same item?

Comment: @SakiburRahman yes two composite item can contain same item also

Comment: i need best way for insert and update records without losing any dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are definitely looking for [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationships, not `one-to-many`. Laravel has excellent features for generating and maintaining a `many-to-many` relationship.

- The `attach/detach` methods are used for single or multiple insertion or deletion in a relation. For example, if you want to add an array of items([1,2]) to a composite item, you can use `attach` like:

  ```
   $compositeItem->items()->attach([1,2]);
  ```

  Same goes for detaching:

  ```
   $compositeItem->items()->detach([1,2]);
  ```
- The `sync` method is used for updating existing records.
     `Sync` is a bit tricky and work exactly like:

  > The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate
  >   table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from
  >   the intermediate table.

  Like if you want to remove 2 and insert 3 you can use `sync` like this:

  ```
  $compositeItem->items()->sync([1,3]);
  ```

Comment: thank you for answer. can you explain me above thing as broadly as i have not used. for example when i add records i have selected item 1,2 then i am going to update records and i have select item 1,2,4 then how will i able to perform that update operation ?

Comment: I have edited my reply for an elaborate illustration.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer or think that it solved your problem, don't forget to accept the answer, it is a common stack overflow behavior that helps build a better understanding  of the question answering echosystem.

Comment: Welcome. My pleasure  :)

Comment: hello i have one issue with jquery select2 plugin. you can help me ?

Comment: i put question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894289/select2-4-0-3-multiple-duplicate-values-need-to-select